# CORS error in Angular - flask socketIO based

Tags: angular, flask, socket.io, cors

I am working on a project where an Angular based app is to communicate with Flask via Socket.IO. my flask code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS

import json

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
#app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'

socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('index.html')


def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    json["user_name"]='Asad'
    json["user_input"]='My Server'
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='localhost', port = 5000)
```

when I try to load my Angular project, it immediately shows a CORS related error. I have tried installing Moesif Origin & CORS Changer and include CORS to the server code as can be seen but no improvement. The Angular code is taken from
[https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/][1]

however, I am not using the websocket server shown in that tutorial as the server from Flask side is being used:

The error shown is:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NCws9C7. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
[1]: https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experience about CORS and it was because I didn't configure my set up properly.

Hints:
Check your Proxy Configuration File
check your proxy Config key

[you can read this digest](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)

Comment: I think you forgot to paste a link

Comment: here is  the link     

https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9